# Backbonejs, behavior of this in a View, Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, cordova

Solved? Not quite.

https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2822

This is a Cordova + Backbone mobile App. I've been banging my head against this one for a while and thought it was time for some help.

```
App.PhotoButtonView = Backbone.View.extend({
pic: "",
picid: 1,

events : {
    "click #addPhotoBtn": "addPhoto"
},

initialize: function( options ) {
    this.options = options;
},
render: function() {

    var html = JST['photo-button/view']({num: this.options.picid});
    $(this.el).html( html );

    setTimeout(this.postrender, 0);
    return this;
},

postrender: function() {
    // reset to default image pic
    console.log('addPhotoBtn' + this.options.picid);
    document.getElementById('addPhotoBtn' + this.options.picid ).src =   this.pic;
    var photo = document.querySelector("#addPhotoBtn" + this.options.picid);
},
```

I'm still getting...

Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'picid' of undefined

but now it's fired by the postrender function. I bet it's something to do with this setTimeout hack.

edit: This is the code in the parent view that initializes the PhotoButtonView

```
postrender: function() {
    $('#submitBtn, .topcoat-button--large').prop('disabled', false);

    this.photo = new App.PhotoButtonView({picid: 1});
    $('#photoButtons').html(this.photo.render().el);

    if (App.activePost.get('photo1')) {
    this.photo2 = new App.PhotoButtonView({picid: 2});
    $('#photoButtons').append(this.photo2.render().el);
    }

    if  (App.activePost.get('photo2')) {
    this.photo3 = new App.PhotoButtonView({picid: 3});
    $('#photoButtons').append(this.photo3.render().el);
    }

    if  (App.activePost.get('photo3')){
    this.photo4 = new App.PhotoButtonView({picid: 4});
    $('#photoButtons').append(this.photo4.render().el);
    }

},
```

Note: A sophomore CS intern wrote this code-base. I'm patching for new functionality.

Comment: How do you initialize your view?

(PS: you probably meant tagName, which by default is 'div' so no need to specify it)

Comment: you might wanna post the actual code that throws your error

Comment: I can see no evidence in the docs (http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) about init parameters getting leaked through to initialize(). You should rely on `this.options` instead.

Comment: Enders, I added some code where I call new
Nikolay, as far as I know, that is the actual code that throws my error. Where else do I need to look?
jhohlfeld, I'll edit this comment when I have results.

Comment: jhohlfeld, this.options is undefined in initialize.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a common mistake regarding the binding of `this`.

Because we're passing the `this.postrender` callback unbound to setTimout, it will be called "function" style in the scope of the global namespace and `this` will be bound to the global object, not the view.

There are two ways we could adjust the setTimeout call so that when referencing `this` in the postrender method it is bound correctly.

Option 1 (call/apply style):

```
setTimeout(this.postrender.bind(this), 0);
```

Option 2 (method style):

```
var that = this;
setTimeout(function () {
  that.postrender();
}, 0);
```

Here's a pretty good article by Yehuda Katz about `this` and invocation.
http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-JavaScript-function-invocation-and-this/